# plot histogram with a last bin tending to Inf

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I want to plot a histogram which includes an `Inf` in its last bin

[0,2.5] ........... [50,Inf]

c (2.5 , 5.0 , 7.5, 10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 35.0, 50.0,  Inf )

refers to endpoints of each bin

[0,2.5] ........... [50,Inf]

> hist ( c (**2.5** , 5.0 , 7.5, 10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 35.0, **50.0**,  **Inf** ),
>      c (6.6  ,12.5  ,15.2 ,16.6 ,15.8 ,11.0 ,13.1  ,4.6  ,3.0  ,1.1  ,0.5 ))

I receive the following error message: `maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'`

Comment: it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.  The second line (`c(6.6,...)`) is interpreted as a `breaks` argument (but it doesn't look right: was this a second data set you wanted to merge with the first?).  If you don't have a `breaks` argument then `Inf` values are silently excluded.

Comment: c (2.5 , 5.0 , 7.5, 10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 35.0, 50.0,  
refers to endpoints of each bin 
i want to represent each value in  c (6.6  ,12.5  ,15.2 ,16.6 ,15.8 ,11.0 ,13.1  ,4.6  ,3.0  ,1.1  ,0.5 )
by a bin : [0,2.5] ...... [50,Inf]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really work very well.

```
brkvec <- c (2.5 , 5.0 , 7.5, 10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 35.0, 50.0, 
             Inf )
dat <- c (6.6 ,12.5 ,15.2 ,16.6 ,15.8 ,11.0 ,13.1 ,4.6 ,3.0 ,1.1 ,0.5 )

hist (dat , breaks=brkvec )
## Error in hist.default(dat, breaks = brkvec) : 
##     some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
```

Add a left breakpoint at zero to deal with this problem:

```
brkvec <- c(0,brkvec)
hist(dat, brkvec)
```

But R doesn't like this:

```
## Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "") : need finite 'xlim' values
```

If we want this we have to hack it a bit by tweaking the axis labels:

```
brkvec2 <- brkvec
brkvec2[brkvec2==Inf] <- max(brkvec2[is.finite(brkvec2)])+1
hist(dat,breaks=brkvec2,col="gray",freq=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic
axis(side=2)
axis(side=1,at=brkvec2,labels=brkvec)
```

... but the last label won't even show up unless you have a very wide plot because of the way R suppresses overlapping labels.  You might prefer:

```
tt <- table(cut(dat,brkvec))
barplot(tt,names=names(tt))
```

This doesn't represent the widths of the categories in any sensible
way, but it would be hard to represent the width of the `(50,Inf]`
category in any case ...

Comment: I am grateful to you for your help and I appreciate your level of effort

Answer (score -1):

```
hist (c(6.6 ,12.5 ,15.2 ,16.6 ,15.8 ,11.0 ,13.1 ,4.6 ,3.0 ,1.1 ,0.5 )),breaks= c(0, 2.5 , 5.0 , 7.5, 10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 35.0, 50.0, Inf))
```

Comment: `Error: unexpected ',' in ...` followed by (after typo-fixing) `Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "") : need finite 'xlim' values`

Comment: oops forgot about inf, what about max(x), instead of inf